# Evaluate Definite Integral to desired accuracy

Tags: integration, power-series

Evaluate $$\int_0^{1/2}x^3\arctan(x)\,dx$$

My work so far:
$x^3\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+4}}{2n+1}$

$$\int_0^{1/2}x^3\arctan(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1/2)^{2n+4}}{2n+1}$$

The desired accuracy needed is to four decimal places, that is were I am stuck.

Comment: You have an alternating series with strictly decreasing terms. The error in using $n$ terms will be at most the absolute value of the $n+1$-th term.

Comment: This is an alternating series, and the terms decrease in absolute value. In such cases, the truncation error is less than the first neglected term. You will have to fool around a bit to see where this is first $\lt 5\times 10^{-5}$. I suggest not using $\sum$ notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote correctly $$x^3\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+4}}{2n+1}$$ but you forgot to integrate with respect to $x$. If you do it $$\int_0^{1/2}x^3\arctan(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(1/2)^{2n+5}}{(2n+1)(2n+5)}$$

As said in the comments, you could start searching for which value of $n$ $$\frac{(1/2)^{2n+5}}{(2n+1)(2n+5)} \leq 5\times 10^{-5}$$ that is to say $$(2n+1)(2n+5)2^{2n+5}  \geq 20000$$ Probably, plotting the function after taking logarithms of both sides will make life easier and $n=2$  satisfies the condition ($23040$ for the lhs).

The other solution, also said in comments, is to start adding the terms and so, you have for the integral $$\frac{1}{160}-\frac{1}{2688}+\frac{1}{23040}=\frac{191}{32256} \simeq 0.00592138$$

If you take the time of computing exactly the integral, as David H suggested in his answer, you probably obtained $$\int x^3\arctan{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{4} x^4 \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(x)$$ and then $$\int_{0}^{1/2}x^3\arctan{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{192} \left(22-45 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \simeq 0.00591592$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You might consider first integrating parts:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1/2}x^3\arctan{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac14x^4\arctan{(x)}\bigg{|}_{0}^{1/2}-\frac14\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\arctan{\left(\frac12\right)}-\frac14\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\arctan{\left(\frac12\right)}-\frac14\int_{0}^{1/2}\left(x^2-1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's just that I was looking to solve the problem using series

Comment: @Guest That's what I assumed you were trying to do. The purpose of my hint was to give you an equivalent integral whose series is easier to calculate. But personally I prefer Claude's direct approach as well.